# Repeat an $http.get request if the result is a filled array in Angularjs 1.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Im searching by date to an API Rest and I need to repeat the request to a day before if the result of the request if an array with 1 item.

```
$http.get('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/festivos-centros/'+ year +'/'+ month + '/'+ day +'/centro/2/')
  .then(function (res) {

    if (res.data.length === 1) {
       // If there is an item in the array repeat the request with the day before until the result of the request is an empty array
    } else {
       // If there are no items in the result then stop
    }
})
```

I think I need to use promises but I don't know how to propose a posible solution, anyone can give me any idea?

Thanks

Comment: you could use a http interceptor and handle the logic in there there you can access all requests / responses and responseerrors and their config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use some recursive function with Date-parameter like this:

```
function myRecursiveSearch(date){
  $http.get('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/festivos-centros/'+ date.getFullYear() +'/'+ (date.getFullYear()) + '/'+ date.getDate() +'/centro/2/')
    .then(function (res) {
      if (res.data.length === 1) {
         date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
         myRecursiveSearch(date);
      } else {
         console.log("I've finished!!!");
      }
  });
}
```

Is it OK?

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion and promises together to achieve this.

First, create a function the can return a date of the previous date from a given date:

```
function dayBefore(d) {
    return new Date(d.getTime() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
}
```

Now create you recursive function:

```
function search(d){
  return $http.get('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/festivos-centros/'+ d.getFullYear() +'/'+ (d.getMonth() + 1) + '/'+ d.getDate() +'/centro/2/')
    .then(function (res) {
      if (res.data.length === 1) {
         return search(dayBefore(d));
      } else {
         return d;
      }
  });
}
```

Now you can use it like so:

```
search(new Date()).then(function(d) {
    console.log(d); // This is the date that the array was empty
});
```

* Note that while the array is not empty the recursion will run - this may be a problem if it is very deep, so you need to set some stop point.